# select all columns based on a specific row value Google-Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula

Hi everybody I am trying to query an already formatted google sheets, I am able to filter some of those data (I used =query(x,select * where ... )). The output I get is the following:

|  |  | may | may | june | june | july | july | july |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| planned | name | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 1 |

Now I want to refer to all the numbers under may (or  june or july) in order to do some operation. I can' t just select the value I want because I need to automate it.

How can I get all the columns containing a specific marker(in my case the name of the month)? If it is not possible can you suggest me a different way to do that ? (I am not very experienced with google sheets or excel)

Comment: What about `FILTER()` function? Like `=FILTER(A1:I2,A2:I2>0)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `query` can't `select` rows, you'd `transpose` it first and then `select` the columns you want and then re`transpose` it back, if needed:

#### Input:

|  |  | may | may | june | june | july | july | july |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| planned | name | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 1 |

#### Formula(select columns >0):

```
=QUERY(TRANSPOSE(A27:I28),"Select * where Col2>0")
```

#### Output:

|  | planned name |
| --- | --- |
| may | 1 |
| june | 1 |
| june | 1 |
| july | 2 |
| july | 3 |
| july | 1 |